# How do i cancel a javascript interval set in a worker thread

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have worker thread set up like this:

```
var worker = new Worker('thread_1.js');
```

In thread_1.js I have an interval set up to post a message back to the main thread every 3 seconds like this:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Worker: Message received from main script');
  function do_something(){
    postMessage("done");    
  } 
  
  myTimer = setInterval(do_something,3000);
  
}
```

In the main thread I have the listener set up as:

```
worker.onmessage = function(e)  {
           console.log(e.data);
        };
```

Then I start the whole process by using:

```
worker.postMessage("start");
```

Everything works as expected but my question is, how do I stop the Interval from the main thread?

Using clearInterval(myTimer) is undefined in the main thread.

Comment: You need to send a message to the worker, and it should have a handler for that message that calls `clearInterval()`.

Comment: The same way you communicate anything to workers—with messages.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could have something like this in your worker

```
let myTimer;
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Worker: Message received from main script');
  function do_something(){
    postMessage("done");    
  } 

  if(e.data === "start") {
    myTimer = setInterval(do_something,3000);
  }
  
  if(e.data === "stop") {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
  }
}
```

and then you can stop it from main thread by simply posting a stop message:

```
worker.postMessage("stop");
```